# Función para cacular el tiempo de atención de tickets dentro de la jornada laboral

Tags: php, laravel, date, report, calculo

necesito me puedan ayudar dándome algunos consejos para el siguiente problema:
Necesito una función (estoy trabajando en LARAVEL aunque no es importante por el momento), donde necesito calcular el tiempo transcurrido de la atención de un tickets de soporte técnico, cuento con la hora de asignación y de cierre del ticket, realizo una diferencia entre ambas fechas:

```
$fecha_inicio = new DateTime($inicio);
$fecha_fin = new DateTime($fin);
$tiempo_tanscurrido = $fecha_inicio->diff($fecha_fin);
```

Pero tengo que validar que el tiempo de atención solo sea calculado dentro de la jornada de trabajo es decir de 08:00 a 16:00, y que valide si el tiempo incluye un fin de semana o un feriado ese tiempo no sea tomado en consideración.

Al momento me encontraba validando el día de asignación para determinar después cuantos días han transcurrido y así poder realizar los cálculos necesarios.

Una consideración que estaba llevando es todo transformar a segundos para poder realizar operaciones mas exactas: a continuación les dejo el código que estaba escribiendo, porque la verdad ya hasta me dolió la cabeza y me perdí a la mitad del camino.

Alguien a realizado alguna función similar o tiene alguna recomendación que me brinde?

```
public function tiempoTranscurrido($inicio, $fin)
{
    //tiempo calculado en segundos
    $no_laboral_mañana = 28800;
    $no_laboral_noche = 28800;
    $no_laboral_fin_semana =172800;

    $restar_segundos = 0;

    //convertir en fecha
    $fecha_inicio = new DateTime($inicio);
    $fecha_fin = new DateTime($fin);
    $tiempo_tanscurrido = $fecha_inicio->diff($fecha_fin);

   if ($tiempo_tanscurrido->m > 0) {
        $mes = (((($tiempo_tanscurrido->m * 30) * 24) * 60) * 60);
   }else{
       $mes = 0;
   }

   if ($tiempo_tanscurrido->d > 0) {
        $dias = ((($tiempo_tanscurrido->d * 24) * 60) * 60);
    }else{
        $dias = 0;
    }

    if ($tiempo_tanscurrido->h > 0) {
        $horas = (($tiempo_tanscurrido->h * 60) * 60);
    }else{
        $horas = 0;
    }

    if ($tiempo_tanscurrido->i > 0) {
        $minutos = ($tiempo_tanscurrido->i * 60);
    }else{
        $minutos = 0;
    }

    $segundos = $tiempo_tanscurrido->s;

    $tiempo_total_segundos = $mes + $dias + $horas + $minutos + $segundos;

    switch(date('N', strtotime($inicio))) {
        case '1':
            if (date('G', strtotime($inicio)) < 8) {
                $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) * 60) + (date('i', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($inicio));
            }else{
                $restar_segundos += 0;
            }

            if($dias <= 0){
                if (date('G', strtotime($fin)) > 16) {
                    $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($fin) - 16) * 60) *60) + (date('i', strtotime($fin)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($fin));
                }else{
                    $restar_segundos += 0;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            if (date('G', strtotime($inicio)) < 8) {
                $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) * 60) + (date('i', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($inicio));
            }else{
                $restar_segundos += 0;
            }

            if($dias <= 0){
                if (date('G', strtotime($fin)) > 16) {
                    $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($fin) - 16) * 60) *60) + (date('i', strtotime($fin)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($fin));
                }else{
                    $restar_segundos += 0;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            if (date('G', strtotime($inicio)) < 8) {
                $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) * 60) + (date('i', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($inicio));
            }else{
                $restar_segundos += 0;
            }

            if($dias <= 0){
                if (date('G', strtotime($fin)) > 16) {
                    $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($fin) - 16) * 60) *60) + (date('i', strtotime($fin)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($fin));
                }else{
                    $restar_segundos += 0;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            if (date('G', strtotime($inicio)) < 8) {
                $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) * 60) + (date('i', strtotime($inicio)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($inicio));
            }else{
                $restar_segundos += 0;
            }

            if($dias <= 0){
                if (date('G', strtotime($fin)) > 16) {
                    $restar_segundos += ((date('G', strtotime($fin) - 16) * 60) *60) + (date('i', strtotime($fin)) * 60) + date('s', strtotime($fin));
                }else{
                    $restar_segundos += 0;
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    dd($restar_segundos);
    return $fecha_fin;
}
```

Como veran dentro del switch valiso del 1 al 4 que corresponden de lunes a jueves, y hasta ahí llegue...
Adicional si se preguntan el `dd($restar_segundos);` eso lo uso para no afectar a la vista y ver el resultado que me va generando.

Comment: O sea que el ticket puede durar varios días abierto pero tu solo quieres contabilizar el tiempo dentro del horario de trabajo?, o no dura más de 1 día.

Comment: si, el ticket puede durar mucho tiempo habierto, lo que necesito contabilizar es el tiempo que se llevo el tecnico para solucionarlo al momento del cierre, pero ese tiempo esta limitado a las 8 horas de la jornada laboral, es decir  si le tomo dos dias calendario (24 horas) el sistema solo debe de contabilizar 2 jornadas laborales (16 horas).